# How to get similar effect on menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu which is developed using bootstrap. Currently it has a CSS transition effect when you hover over each item I line is placed under each heading. I can't seem to figure out how can I do the same but on top of the heading and the transition effect coming from the other direction.

The code I have so far is

```
.navbar ul li:after {
content:'';
display: block;
height: 4px;
width: 0;
transition: width .6s ease, background-color .6s ease;
}
.navbar ul li:hover:after {
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
}
```

I have created a JSFiddle **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zpxtre6n/1/)**

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navbar ul li:before,
.navbar ul li:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 0;
    background: #fff;
    transition: width .6s ease, background-color .6s ease;
}
.navbar ul li:before{ top:0;    right:0; }
.navbar ul li:after { bottom:0; left:0;  }

.navbar ul li:hover:before,
.navbar ul li:hover:after{ width: 100%; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/zpxtre6n/4/

Comment: I want the bottom effect to stay as it is. This removes the bottom effect

Comment: @Code it was not clear initially from what you asked. Gimme a sec.

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/zpxtre6n/5/

just add `float:right` for your `.navbar ul li:after` and `float:left` for  `.navbar ul li:before`

```
.navbar ul li:after, .navbar ul li:before {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 0;
    float:right;
    transition: width .6s ease, background-color .6s ease;
}
.navbar ul li:before{
    float:left;
}
.navbar ul li:hover:after, .navbar ul li:hover:before  {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
```